# Editing Word documents

Tags: ms-word

I have to collaborate with someone who uses Word.  I can open the document
(which has comments) in Libre-Office, but I want a proper editing environment.
What can I do?

Comment: I am often in the same boat and never found a good solution.  Either they make the edits and I tell them what my proposed revisions are, or visa versa.  I use LaTeX, which no one in my profession uses.

Comment: As much as I hate Word documents, the same problem shows up between users of DocBook and users of LaTeX.  To make interoperability really working, you'd need a "round-trip" conversion which preserves every detail of everything (e.g. comments in the LaTeX document).

Comment: This is probably even worse than what aplaice offers, but, unfortunately, I had to deal with a similar problem too. And, if the edits are really minimal, it is possible to edit the XML document directly (`docx` is just a ZIP archive containing a lot of garbage XMLs and eventually XLS or images). You can extract the archive, find the relevant document (typically, `word/document.xml`), and edit it by hand (the markup isn't too difficult to figure out), but it's an onerous task, if you need to do this often.

Answer (score 3):

A sub-optimal answer (but I don't think there's currently anything better):

You could use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert the docx document into a more emacs-friendly format (like markdown or org-mode), edit it in emacs and then convert back to docx. Apparently, pandoc does now have [some support for docx comments](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1561). However, I have no idea how terribly mangled the formatting and the comments would be by the conversion there and back again.

Comment: This is a pretty good approach. I've tested, for example, starting with org-mode, but without hyperlinks, TODO lists and other features that obviously don't exist in Word. Then, pandoc it to docx, pandoc it back to a new org-mode and compare. The files are different but not particularly mangled.